# Keycloak protected API trying to expose swagger.json

Tags: spring-boot, jersey-2.0, keycloak

I have an API built with SpringBoot, Jersey2, and Keycloak. I'm using the SpringBoot adapter as well as the SpringAdapter. Everything is fine.

I now stumble upon this page https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5

And started to use the swagger-core package to generate a `swagger.json` file for my API. The swagger-jersey2 dependency will expose the `swagger.json` file at a link like this: `http://localhost:8080/swagger.json`. However, I can't access that url publicly because keycloak blocks it.

In my `SecurityConfig` class below I have the following:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{
    //....other code above
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("*").permitAll();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
}
```

How do I alter the configuration to allow the `swagger.json` to be accessed without needing to pass a bearer token? (I tested accessing with a bearer token and it worked but I need it accessible without a bearer token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by doing the following:

1. Create a new `PubliResource` annotation.
2. Created a list at startup of the classes annotated with `PublicResource` and then explicitly let requests threw on those classes even if no token was detected.

```java
import java.lang.annotation.*;

/***
 * Used for marking a class accessible to a non-authorized user for
 * @GET, @PUT, @POST, and @DELETE annotations
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Inherited
public @interface PublicResource {

}
```

Then I made an `AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter` bean.

```java
import org.keycloak.KeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterUtils;
import org.keycloak.adapters.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private static Set<String> nonAuthenticationWhiteListSet = new TreeSet<>();

    static {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.forPackages("com.package.code.resources"); //IMPORTANT
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(configurationBuilder);
        Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(PublicResource.class);
        for (Class<?> annotatedClass : annotated) {
            if (!annotatedClass.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
                continue;
            }
            String classPath = annotatedClass.getAnnotation(Path.class).value();

            for (Method method : annotatedClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                String fullPath = classPath;
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(GET.class)
                        || method.isAnnotationPresent(POST.class)
                        || method.isAnnotationPresent(PUT.class)
                        || method.isAnnotationPresent(DELETE.class)) {
                    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Path.class)) {
                        fullPath += method.getDeclaredAnnotation(Path.class).value();
                    }

                    fullPath = fullPath.replaceAll("\\{.*\\}", "[^/]+");
                    nonAuthenticationWhiteListSet.add(fullPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (!(request instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Expecting a HTTP request");
        }

        RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext context = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) request.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());

        if (context == null) {
            handleNoSecurityContext(request, response, chain);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private void handleNoSecurityContext(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String path = httpRequest.getPathInfo();

        if (isPublicResource(path)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        ((HttpServletResponse) response).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return;
    }

    private boolean isPublicResource(String path) {
        for (String regex : nonAuthenticationWhiteListSet) {
            if (path.matches(regex)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in my main class I did this so it would get registered as a filter.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class, SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class MyApi {

    //...other code plus the main method

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter authFilter() {
        return new AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter();
    }
}
```